# xpages and dojo date text box format

Tags: date, dojo, format, xpages

I'm trying to format a Dojo date text box on an XPage when the page is opened for reading.

When I edit the XPage the correct format is dd/MM/yyyy is displayed.

I already tried the pattern , the constraint, lang properties of component, and also tried the application locale but nothing solved the problem.

Does anyone know how to format the date to dd/MM/yyyy format?

Example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
         xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument var="document1" formName="Test"
            action="editDocument">
        </xp:dominoDocument>
    </xp:this.data>    
    <xe:djDateTextBox id="djDateTextBox1" value="#{document1.Date}">
        <xe:this.constraints>
            <xe:djDateTimeConstraints datePattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
        </xe:this.constraints>
    </xe:djDateTextBox>
    <xp:br />
    <xp:button value="save" id="button1"
        rendered="#{javascript:document1.isEditable()}">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
            refreshMode="complete" immediate="false" save="true">
            <xp:this.action>
                <xp:changeDocumentMode mode="readOnly" var="document1" />
            </xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
    <xp:button value="edit" id="button2"
        rendered="#{javascript:!document1.isEditable()}">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
            refreshMode="complete">
            <xp:this.action>
                <xp:changeDocumentMode mode="edit" var="document1" />
            </xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
</xp:view>
```

Comment: Please show us your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact I found that **showReadonlyAsDisabled** property component in read mode maintain the formatting of the date.

```xml
<xe:djDateTextBox id="djDateTextBox1" value="#{document1.Date}"
    showReadonlyAsDisabled="true">
    <xe:this.constraints>
        <xe:djDateTimeConstraints datePattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
    </xe:this.constraints>
</xe:djDateTextBox>
```